# Cucumber Not able to see the element generated by javascript

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I am testing an application using cucumber with capybara.

The page which I am testing has one textfield and whenever we change value textfield, the update link comes with jQuery or javascript.

I am changing the value in textbox using capybara through cucumber step.
I next step when I am searching for that link it is saying that no link with id, text and name.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the `@javascript` tag to the scenario, to make it run in a browser which supports Javascript.  Otherwise the default behaviour is to run without Javascript support, so the script which adds the link to the page will never get executed.

Comment: I have checked it with @javascript and also with selenium, It is not working.

Comment: Can you see the link being added to the page if you watch the test running in the browser?  Try adding a `sleep(30)` statement immediately after changing the text value - this will give you time to see the link appear, and inspect it to verify that the ID/text is exactly the same as what you're using with `click_link`.

Comment: Jon, I have done all this , the link is showing there when I am running it with @selenium, it is showing there,but it is not able be click it and I have also try to check whether the the anchor tag with text "update" is present or not using capybara but it is giving same  error. "No element with id, name or text"

Comment: It would help if you added some code to your question - the step definition in which you're attempting to click the link, and as much as you can of the page source, and jQuery script that creates the link.

Comment: This is my html ::==>>>


<p>
<label>Activities Label</label>
<input id="activities_label_p_id" name="system_setting[activity_label]" reload_window_on_update="true" type="text" value="Activity" />
<span><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="settings_text_field($(this))">update</a></span>
</p>
<h3 class='section_div'>Dashboard</h3>
<p>      One thing I have noticed here , this html link is viewable when I inspect element, but not viewable when I did view source.

Comment: When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/ do |link, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    click_link(link)
end

Comment: And this is my jquery code

 $('form.settingsform input:text').always().keyup(function() {
  var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
    if (rel != 'company_name') {
      $(this).next("span").html("<a style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='settings_text_field($(this))'>update</a>");
    }
 });
})

Comment: And this is jquery function :

function settings_text_field(link){
  link.hide().spin();
  link.parents('form:first').ajaxSubmit(function(){
   link.next().remove();
    link.show();
   link.hide().next("span");
    var input_field = link.parents("span").prev();
    if (input_field && input_field.attr("reload_window_on_update") == 'true'){
      window.location.reload();
    }
 });
  return false;
}

Comment: Thanks, can you also include the scenario that you're using to call the step?

Comment: Also, this would be much easier to read if you edited the original question and put these snippets inline - there's no formatting down here in the comments!